# I get an error while doing "py to exe". how to solve

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I get an error while doing "py to exe".

This is my error:

````
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xfc' in file C:\Users\Eyüphan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details ```
````

Comment: What did you conclude after referring to http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ like the error message suggests?

Comment: SInce you're new to SO, I would provide a lot more detail in what you are trying to do, including the steps you've already taken to debug yourself.  This community is to provide assistance when you've done your homework and can provide more information,  It's not a post-and-pray forum.